# Reading from the end of a drive with dd

Tags: linux, dd

How can I read from the end of a drive with `dd`? I thought about using `size - to_read` but I have no idea how to get the size in bytes.

Comment: See this Question http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13848/wipe-last-1mb-of-a-hard-drive

Answer (score 3):

Does it have to be 'dd'?  GNU 'ddrescue' has a convenient "reverse" option:

```
  # copy the last 1K from '/dev/sdc' to '/tmp/c_end'
  % ddrescue  --reverse  --max-size=1Ki /dev/sdc /tmp/c_end


  Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
  rescued:      1024 B,  errsize:       0 B,  current rate:     1024 B/s
     ipos:         0 B,   errors:       0,    average rate:     1024 B/s
     opos:         0 B,     time from last successful read:       0 s
  Finished
```

Comment: does not work, still copies first bytes...

Answer (score 1):

Get a total size of a disk, in bytes:

```
fdisk -l /dev/sda  

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1           7       56196   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2               8         257     2008125   83  Linux
/dev/sda3             258      121602   974698231+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
```

Get last 100 bytes from the disk with dd:

```
  dd if=/dev/sda of=/tmp/endofdisk.data bs=1 skip=1000204885916 count=100
```

Notice the total size of disk on the first line of fdisk output.
I used 1-byte block size, but of course if you're copying more than a couple of bytes, use 1K or 1M blocks. Calculate the size manually (divide by 1024) and replace `bs=1` with `bs=1024` for 1K blocks.

Comment: I cannot mount the disk, I read it as whole (no partitions)

Comment: @Dani: I changed my answer, use fdisk instead of df.

Comment: I cannot use fdisk because the partition table is messed up. it just takes 2 min and returns and writes nothing.